# remove all words in front of a consistent known sub string

Tags: sql, string, substring

I am trying to remove all words in front of a consistent known sub string ("To Find a"). I would like to remove everything in front of "To Find a" in bulk over 600 `Description`strings. The words in front of this sub string are different in all cases. For example (`Description` 'Some Text, Some More Text…To Find a… Some More Text') I have red several other posts and have tried using TRIM, CHARINDEX, and SUBSTRING_INDEX.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is your RDBMS vendor?

Comment: what exactly have you tried? It woould be possible with the functions you mentioned.

Comment: not sure what RDBMS vendor means... Sorry

Comment: I lost track of what I have tried. I'm very new to SQL and I was just trying to apply all kinds of methods found on this site... but no luck

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? DB2? SQL Server? Firebird? MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is SQL Server, a relatively easy way to remove the leading bit would be with the help of [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) and [CHARINDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('To Find a', ColumnName), 2147483647)
FROM YourTable;
```

The CHARINDEX function finds the position of the substring, and the result is used as SUBSTRING's second argument. The length argument is set to the maximum `int` value to make sure all the remaining characters to the end of the string are returned. (You don't need to calculate the exact number.) If the substring isn't found, CHARINDEX returns 0. In this context, 0 as the starting position causes the entire string value to be returned.

If you actually want to do the opposite, i.e. *keep* the leading text and remove the rest, as one of your comments seems to imply, you could try using CHARINDEX and [LEFT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) in this way:

```
SELECT LEFT(ColumnName, CHARINDEX('To Find a', ColumnName + 'To Find a') - 1)
FROM YourTable;
```

Again, CHARINDEX returns the position of `'To Find a'` in the column value. After subtracting 1, that becomes the length argument of LEFT. To make sure CHARINDEX does find the search term, the term is appended to the value being searched: if the original value doesn't have `'To Find a'`, CHARINDEX hits the appended bit and returns the position after the last character of the original string, which, when subtracted, becomes the string's exact length.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server to select the leading text:

```
DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(255) = 'Some Text, Some More Text…To Find a… Some More Text'
SELECT LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX('To Find a',@String)-1)
```

(Assuming string is consistently present, as stated in question)

To remove the leading text:

```
DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(255) = 'Some Text, Some More Text…To Find a… Some More Text'
SELECT RIGHT(@String,CHARINDEX(REVERSE('To Find a'),REVERSE(@String))-1)
```

If you want to keep the 'To Find a' then you adjust the `-1` near the end of the query.

Update:

If 'to find a' isn't in every string, and using your table:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('To Find a',YourField) > 0
                THEN LEFT(YourField,CHARINDEX('To Find a',YourField)-1)
            ELSE YourField
       END AS 'FixedField'
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: If 'To Find a' is leading text of @string it has encounter an error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.'

Comment: Question states 'consistent known substring'.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure how to use "DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(255)"  To be more specific I have hundreds of videos with random descriptions in a FIELD called `Description`. However, I have found many have the words "to find a" in the middle of the description as a starting point to the remaining description that I would like to remove. The beginning of each description is different as well. I'm trying to avoid doing them one by one if possible. You probably already answered my question I just do not understand how to implement it. Sorry for my ignorance. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So you want to keep the part before "to find a", right?
The variable is just a way to test string manipulation, you create a variable `@string` and `SELECT` it rather than your table, I'll adjust answer above.